# PHP server log errors

Tags: php

please some one help me

```
PHP Fatal error:  require_once() enter code here[<a     href='function.require'>function.require</a>]: Failed opening required     '/include/tables.php' (include_path='.:/usr/lib/php:/usr/local/lib/php') in     /home2/uaeadver/public_html/include/include.php on line 14
```

what is this all about i am including the include.php also here

```
   $path=dirname(__FILE__);
   global $minimal;

   if(!file_exists($path.'/../config.php')) header("Location: install/");     
   require_once($path.'/../config.php');

   if(!isset($config_abs_path) || !isset($config_live_site))  header("Location: install/");

   require_once($config_abs_path.'/include/tables.php');
```

Comment: show your code and path where is tables.php and include .php

Comment: Is `tables.php` in the same folder with `include.php`

Comment: You're including `/include/tables.php` in a file included in `/include/` which means you're including `/include/include/tables.php`.

Comment: i think your file include path is missing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try if both files in same dir

```
require_once('include.php');
```

and use to exit dir `../` like

```
require_once('../include.php');
```

Comment: thanks for ur reply rakesh , but i am afraid to tell i am not much aware of php and all so can u please help me in this regard , i was even looking for some php people to help but they are asking lumpsum amount of money

Comment: echo $config_abs_path.'/include/tables.php and show your output

Comment: can i have ur email id or something i really need help if so can u please check the errors

Answer (score 0):

The way you try to get to your base directory is not really working or the file you try to include does not exist.

Use the function `getcwd()` to let return your current work directory if it helps.

Generally, you start your *application* from always the same path, you could `define()` an absolute base path and use that instead:

```
// define'd constants are always global scope:
define('BASE_PATH', '/home2/uaeadver/public_html/');

require(BASE_PATH . 'include/config.php');
```

Missing `exit;` after Location change:

```
if(!file_exists($path.'/../config.php')) {
    header("Location: install/"); 
    exit;
}
```

Your codestyle really needs improvement. Don't use globals, try real design patterns and strict coding standards.

Comment: its a classified script from oxyclassifieds they told that its the latest and gave all this things i never new the codestyle was outdated

Comment: @user3640582 oh lol. they have errors in the scripts and code style from 1999 in there.. seriously not serious :D Try to replace `require_once($config_abs_path.'/include/tables.php');` by `require_once('tables.php');`

Comment: is it possible to change the code styles in future sorry to ask i am a newbie to this thats why asking you deeply and really thanks for ur help buddy

Comment: @user3640582 you can find lots of information when searching for `php design pattern` and `php code style`